# Reliably test execution times in Java

Tags: java, performance

I am currently testing in Java whether the use of a *custom class* or *int arrays* as a datatype is faster and ran speed tests for that purpose (see below).

```java
int repetitions = 1000000000;

for (int i = 0; i < repetitions*10; i++) {
    Move move3 = new Move(2, 3);
    int sum3 = move3.x + move3.y;
}

// object block
long start = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
    Move move2 = new Move(2, 3);
    int sum2 = move2.x + move2.y;
}
System.out.println("Object took " + (System.nanoTime() - start) + "ns");

// array block
long start2 = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; i++) {
    int[] move = new int[]{2, 3};
    int sum = move[0] + move[1];
}
System.out.println("Array took " + (System.nanoTime() - start2) + "ns");
```

**Swapping around the timing blocks basically decides what is faster**. This was by a factor of 4 originally, but running the meaningless first block beforehand reduced it to a factor of about 1.1. Why is this? Is there a "warmup period" for the JVM? And how could I get completely rid of the issue?

(I know, I can get all performance-related information from the fact that swapping changes the advantage, but I am curious what is happening here.)

Comment: the first block might affect your comparison for you allocates a lot of memory for by creating new object inside the loop... I changed your repetitions variable to 2000000000 and the factor becomes around 1.1 (without the first block), you can try not to create any object in your first block...

Comment: @wenzi more repetitions and removing the first block doesnt change much, its still a factor of around 2-3. Maybe its a hardware dependent issue? I even ran it Integer.MAX_VALUE times and it still is a factor of 1.8

Comment: If I use Integer.MAX_VALUE, this is the closest result: Object took 1495768764ns
Array took 1463381341ns (without first block)

Comment: Ok, no clue why it is different for me but thanks for confirming that there is actually no real time difference!

Comment: sure... the array seems to be a little more efficient... maybe you could try clean up your project or restart jvm? not an expert on this but this post is interesting

Comment: I suppose, the linked question help. Put simply: Use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/). Bachmarking Java is too hard, that's why we've got JMH.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually the warm up for the JVM. Try to look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jvm-warmup).